# Rails Mandatory Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know it is possible to create a default_scope in Rails models to restrict the selection. But this can/will be overridden by an unscoped call.

Is it possible to have a scope which is applied by default regardless of the Rails scoping methods? Something that can be done with initialize method?

Comment: That makes no sense. If a scope is "mandatory" to the point where you cannot circumvent it, you probably need to rethink how you're structuring your data.

Comment: I know it does not make sense in a normal scenario. I was trying out options to simulate multiple inheritance, or something of that sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can monkey patch ActiveRecord::Base methods.

See the unscoped method:

```
def unscoped #:nodoc:
  block_given? ? relation.scoping { yield } : relation
end
```

You should monkey patch #relation method to include your default scope.

Place the following file in `config/initializers` directory:

```
module ActiveRecord

  class Base

    def relation
      base_relation = super
      base_relation.where(#default conditions)
    end
  end
end
```

You can also use ActiveSupport::Concern which may be the preferred way, I just wanted to point out that you should extend the `#relation` method. Regardless of which way you extend ActiveRecord my recommendation is that you should stick with the `#default_scope` method and write the necessary tests to ensure that the relations are not being unscoped.